# How can I run ctags for directories listed in a file?

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

I have a file containing list of over 400 directories with verilog files that I want in run ctags program. My ctags program can handle verilog files. Suppose the file `List1` starts like this :

```
../../nxpdsn/nxpx_adb400/build/nxpx_adb400/logical/adb400_r3_ace_lite_dvm_scp/verilog
../../nxpdsn/nxpx_adb400/build/nxpx_adb400/logical/adb400_r3_ace_lite_scp/verilog
../../nxpdsn/nxpx_adb400/build/nxpx_adb400/logical/adb400_r3_axi3_1/verilog
../../nxpdsn/nxpx_adb400/build/nxpx_adb400/logical/adb400_r3_axi4_scp/verilog
....
```

How can run ctags for these directories?

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of `ctags -R $(cat List1)`?

Comment: Ah, that looks nice. though I was looking for any option that takes a list file.

Comment: Putting a little more thought into it, and looking at your example list, it looks like maybe you're looking for it to only look in those directories specifically, and not to recurse down, so the `--maxdepth` option may be useful.  And it seems it does have an option for passing a list with `-L`, so maybe `ctags -R --maxdepth 1 -L List1`? (not sure if depth should be 0 or 1 without testing)

Comment: yap! it works. (except my ctags  version doesn't take --maxdepth). Please write a short answer so I can select it. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I like this $(cat list) which concatenates all the lines.